# Clear input after submitting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that I'm using to update a value remotely. To be more specific, on one side, I have a screen connected to the internet with a little field in it that reads (Now Serving: ##) and on the other side, I have a tablet connected to the internet with a webpage that is used to push the value to the screen and update it. Everything looks good except the following: 
Getting the input field to clear after it submits the value so I can type another number in it without the need to manually clear it

Below is my HTML Code

```
<div id="container">
<div id="logoDiv"></div>
    <h3>Type the number in the box</h3>
    <div class="theWork">
        <div id="formDiv">
            <FORM NAME="test" class="theForm">
                Now Serving:    <input type="text" name="msg1" class="testingHuss" id="theOrderBox" autofocus ><br>
            </FORM>
        </div>
        <div id="onScreenDiv"><span id="onscreen"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testingHuss').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        sendCommand("galaxy.signage.me", "wmt_huss", "husshuss", "3", "nowServing", document.test.msg1.value);
        document.getElementById('onscreen').innerHTML = document.test.msg1.value;
            return false;

         }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('testingHuss').val('') will empty the input. Call that when you are done with the data inside

Comment: If you're using jQuery please add the tag.

Comment: thanks for your quick response can you please tell me where exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.test.msg1.value =""

Before return false

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Jquery you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testingHuss').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            //Do Necesary stuff when enter was pressed.
            $(event.currentTarget).val('');            
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fgqs4hzb/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jquery replace this line:

```
updateTextInput(session, "testingHuss", value = "")
```

with:

```
$('.testingHuss').val('');
```